# How to define UTF-8 encoding for Eclipse Plugin Project

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, eclipse-plugin

I created a plugin which reads the file of format UTF-8 and displays it in a label.

If I run the Eclipse plugin project through runconfiguration -> changing the encoding to UTF-8, it is working fine by displaying the special characters also.

But when I created a plugin and installed it on Eclipse, it is choosing the default encoding type and not displaying the special characters properly.

**How can I make my plugin always run in UTF-8 encoding after packaging it into the plugin?**

Here is my code to read a file:

```
        File file = new File("D:\\StringFile.txt");
    String Message = "";
    try {
        if (file.exists()) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(file));
            String str;

            System.out.println("File found");
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

                if (str.contains("GER")) {
                    Message = str.split(" : ")[1];
                    System.out.println("Message -- " + Message);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Label message = new Label(dialog, SWT.LEFT);
...
    message.setText(Message);
```

Comment: If you want to read a file with a specific encoding you should specify that encoding when you open the file. Show us the code you are using to read the file.

Comment: i edited the post with code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the encoding of a file you should specify it when you open file. To do that use `InputStreamReader` instead of `FileReader`:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
```

Note: `StandardCharsets` requires Java 7 or later, use `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` if you want this to work with earlier release of Java.

Note: For files in an Eclipse workspace your plugin should use the `IFile` API.